# Non standard guitar strings for old guitar

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, jazz, strings

I have a old jazz guitar Framus 5/50 or 5/51(I really do not know the difference)

I bought standard D'Addario strings but they are too short. All parts on guitar are at the right place and they are all original.

What strings should I get? How is that standard called? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Unbelievable that standard strings are too short!

Comment: I agree, Tim. I went to the store and tried multiple strings. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've worked on some classic arch-top floating tailpiece guitars before, and I recall the strings were close, but still able to reach enough to wind on the posts.

Some string manufacturers may have slightly different lengths, which would take some searching on the manufacturer's web sites for info.

There are some custom string manufacturers as well, that will make string sets to order, including length.  You will pay a premium price for them though.

Another option would be to use a set of Baritone Guitar strings, which are made longer for the longer scale length.  You would probably have to replace the high E string with a single to make up for the thicker gauges the sets come with.

Some of the "Gypsy Jazz" guitar sets may be longer for the arch tops also.

EDIT: (cleaning up multiple edits:)

12 string guitar sets may work also, some will be as long as 43 inches

Looking at some of the Framus history sites, that may not be an original tail-piece; in the picture it looks a little shorter than some of the stock pictures. I have seen that style of tailpiece in a couple of different lengths on vintage instruments. 
You might consider putting a longer tail-piece on.

From what I've found, the dimensions of the guitar are a 24 inch scale length, with a total length of the guitar at 37.5 inches. Product recommendations are off topic for this site, but searching for a manufacturer's name and "string length" will usually get you results. For example, D'Addario strings come in at 39 inches, which should be just long enough to start at the furthest pegs.

One of that guitar model I saw for sale is listed as having a D'Addario Phosphor Bronze set installed, so apparently that is long enough.

--

You can start the strings in the plain steel portion, you do not have to get all the way into the winding. The main strength of the string is the core, and it should hold the tension even if you don't get winding onto the post, so the strings may seem too short, but will still work if you have enough length to get them started.

--

Inserting from my comment: Looking at the headstock, the shape looks different than other examples of the stock guitars I've found pictures of. So far it looks like the stock headstocks had a curved top, or narrow square shoulders in one example. The headstock on yours is wide at the top and looks like it has some carving coming into the pegs starting at the nut. I also haven't seen any examples that don't have a truss rod slot in the headstock.

One of the problems these old archtops (Kay included) have is a tendency to have neck problems, either with the action getting too high to use, or warping.

It may be that you have a neck replacement and a longer scale length was used, adding to the overall length of the guitar.

You can measure from the nut to the 12th fret, and double that number to get the scale length. The stock length should be at 24 inches. If it is bigger than that, you may have a different scale length neck installed. Because the bridge is floating, you should be able to compensate if this is the case, once you find strings that fit.

Comment: I am pretty sure that tailpiece is original, please take a look at this guitar https://reverb.com/au/item/5714230-framus-5-50-1959-small-archtop-guitar-vintage-made-in-germany-free-shipping-to-the-usa I will buy multiple sets of strings and try them, I guess..

Comment: Another example https://www.stageguitarservice.com/product-page/1965-framus-calypso-5-50 What brands or sets do you recommend me to try first?

Comment: I answered the comments in the answer.

Comment: Also, you might look at getting some replacement tuner ferrules.  It looks like the tuning machines were replaced and the ferrules that came with the set didn't fit the post holes (a common problem) mini thin wall ferrules are sold from various luthier supply shops, and on the internet.

Comment: Aaaand, looking again at the picture, I now see that the headstock looks different that the pictures of stock models, so you may be dealing with a neck replacement that is a different scale length, which would also cause the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I did know that the neck was replaced.. Interesting..  Regarding the strings, I bought the bronze 85/15 daddario ez900 and only few strings fit, but that leaded me to another problem, the guitar is buzzing.. I guess that i have to buy multiple sets and fit the strings that fit?

Comment: The problem is going to be the extra length from the bridge to the tailpiece. The standard neck is going to add a couple inches, looks like enough to pass standard string length. D'Addario doesn't seem to make the 85/15s anymore. You should measure the length of the strings. If they aren't 39 inches they may be counterfeit.  I would say try either a 12string guitar set or the baritone guitar strings.  Otherwise you could find a longer tailpiece to move the string ends closer to the bridge.  You'll want to measure from the tailpiece to the furthest tuner and get an actual length to look for.

Comment: The buzzing may be correctable by raising the adjustable bridge. You'll want to check the correct location of the bridge by testing the harmonic at the 12th fret with the fretted note there, and move the bridge until they are close to the same note.

Comment: Whoa, you opened my eyes, I did not know that 85/15 isnt in production anymore. Package and the store looks legitimate, but I am not sure, I do not have much experience with strings. I picked some set of strings randomly and strings fit as expected. That set had few centimeters longer strings and just enough to fit. I guess that I can continue my restoration in peace and know that when I finish it that I will be able to play it :)))) Thank you soo soooo much for help and lots of information,  Alphonso Balvenie! <3

Answer (score 0):

Standard strings should be long enough.  You should take the guitar with you to the music store where you get the strings.  They should be able to help you there.

Comment: Not in my store, haha! The guy was angry when he saw me come back second time..

Comment: Why would he not want another customer?

Comment: So he can have fun playing with other guitars, I guess? Idk, skinny peacock.